# Set index.asp as default homepage

Tags: asp.net, iis

Please have in mind I am totally new to asp.net

I have a customer that needs his old asp website to be seen on the new hosting while the new website is being developed.

I have uploaded the asp files on the server, but index.asp does not load when typing the domain on the browser (example: www.customerdomain.com)

Browser message:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

It does load when accesing it directly (example: www.customerdomain.com/index.asp)

Searching into the old files, there is a `web.config` file containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
        <add value="index.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="home.aspx" />
        <add value="home.asp" />
        <add value="home.htm" />
        <add value="home.html" />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="default.asp" />
        <add value="default.htm" />
        <add value="default.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As this did not work on loading index.asp by default, I tried changing it to this one, as seen on several topics related to this issue:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.asp" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

None of this worked.

How can I make index.asp load as homepage?

Comment: this probally belongs better on [sf]

Comment: You should probably have separate developer and production environments so that any changes you make with the developer environment doesn't affect production.

Comment: *Searching into the old files, there is a `web.config`" - where in the folder hierarchy?